# Nectcat end connection

Tags: bash, shell, connection, netcat

Im using netcat to send files to another pc, using a client and a server.
the problem is when i send a file from server to client, the content of the file is send, but the program doesnt continue in both computers.

Code from server:

```
($nc -nlv $server < xa.txt)
```

Code from client:

```
($nc $ip_server $door > xa1.txt)
echo "done"
```

In this case doesnt show the echo, and recieves the file in the console, made the connections and the square is full colour.

Comment: I can't understand your last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal: `netcat` reads until end of input on one side, and writes until end of connection. It is designed like this.

If you want to transfer several file, use a protocol intended for this: `sftp`, `scp`, `rsync`.

Another way is to use `tar` and `netcat`. On the receiving end do:

```
$ nc -lv $port | tar xvfz -
```

and on the sending end do:

```
$ tar cfz - * | nc $host $port
```

Answer (score 1):

use timeout options, such as

```
-q seconds   after EOF is detected, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit.
```

or

```
-w secs      timeout for connects and final net reads
```

Well, I think that you won`t be needing -w.

However, ncat(insecure.org, these guys who created nmap) disconnects as soon as it sees EOF.